# JavaScript - Navigate to a Named Anchor

Tags: javascript

I have an named HTML anchor tag that works like a bookmark. This tag is defined as:

```
<a name="myLocation"></a>
```

I need to be able to jump to this link via JavaScript. How do I jump to a location in my HTML page from JavaScript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
window.location = window.location + "#myLocation";
```

Hope this helps.